# What is the difference and efficiency between main() and run()?

Tags: java

So I'm very new to the JSwing world, having not covered much in my AP Computer Science class I finished last year. So, I am familiar with inheritance and all the core parts of the Java language, but I can't see the difference between the two methods main() and run().

My code here works just fine for right now:

Main Class:

```html
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Component;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class Main {
 
 private JFrame frame;
 
 
 public Main() {
  
  frame = new JFrame("SoundCombine"); //Create frame
  
  frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE); //Close the frame when |x| button is pressed
  
  //Add components to the frame
  JButton button = new JButton();
  frame.getContentPane().add(button, BorderLayout.CENTER);
  
  frame.pack();
  
  frame.setVisible(true);
 }
 
}
```

Run Class:

```html
public class Run {
 
 public static void main(String args[]){
  
  new Main();
 
 }

}
```

However, I've also seen this method of starting JSwing applications:

```html
SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        createAndShowGUI();
    }
});
```

What is the big difference between the two? What sort of problems would I encounter down the road by using either one of the two. Although there are many different ways to write the same program, I want to know the conventional way of going about this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're asking what's the difference between an orange and a buffalo -- these are two completely different things.

- The main method is the entry point of all Java programs, even those without main methods such as applets where there actually is a main method, but it's hidden from view.
- The `run` method you speak of is a method that needs to be part of any class that implements a Runnable interface. This is not the entry point for programs to start.
- Your example above, that is to feed a Runnable into  the `SwingUtilities.invokeLater(...)` method is a way to guarantee that the code within the Runnable's run method is called on the Swing event thread, something that you want to do when starting Swing (**not** JSwing) applications for thread safety purposes, since if you don't do this, there are risks of errors (actually exceptions) being thrown.
- Swing applications still need a main method regardless of whether you queue them on the Swing event thread or not. It's not "either use main or run", since again, they are totally different animals.
- Just because some code "works for now" is no guarantee that it will work later. Threading exceptions are notorious for occurring intermittently and when least desired.

Comment: That makes a lot more sense, thanks. I figured it would create problems down the road.